# Must Swift 3rd party packages match the swift versions in the app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, cocoapods

I started to study SwiftUI 3 and Swift 5.6 for iOS development, but if I want to add a 3rd party package from Swift Package Manager or cocopods must that package use the exact same swift version as my xcode/iOS app is using, or can it be a lower Swift version?

For example I am using swift 5.6 in my project and this package seems to be using swift v5.2 https://github.com/meilisearch/meilisearch-swift

Comment: `swift-tools-version` refers to the minimum swift version of the package, plus the swift packages are fetched as source files and compiled with the builds settings from your project.

Comment: Swift version do not need to match. However while compiling it might give you errors/warnings based on if anything has been deprecated or obsoleted that you will need to handle accordingly